# How to use Http filters in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq17s.png)In my .net core Api I'm referring .net project, which contains ActionFilterAttribute, ExceptionFilterAttribute implementation (HTTP filters custom classes)

But I'm not able to register it globally in
.Net core, type mismatch issue comes because in .net core for Filters we have different all ( Aspnet.Mvc.core).

Need suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Put the code where you are facing issue? Also provide the core version which you are using. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for the same.

Comment: I have added Image in my question, "enter image description here", Please see that.. I tried adding the comment with code, but not able to save my edits.

Comment: Please paste code as text, and format as code using Markdown. Don’t include code as a screenshot.